# How to selected value after refreshing the page??

Tags: php, html

after refreshing the PHP web page, how to show selected value in dropdown?? 
This is my code...

```
<select name="dropdown-list">
     <option value="1">Test1</option>
     <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3/option>
    </select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you performed? Or perhaps you just came straight here because it's free.

Comment: If i will select any option value then it should be show as selected after refreshing the page, how it will possible??

Comment: It's almost like you ignored my comment entirely and responded to some comment that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Give the `option` you wish to be selected the [`selected` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected):

```
<select name="dropdown-list">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3/option>
</select>
```

In this case, the "Test2" option is selected.

Comment: James Donnelly, If i will select option value 2 then after refreshing the page how this will show selected ???

Comment: I'd need to know more information in order to answer that. How is your `select` element being populated and added to the page? What causes the option to be selected? How is this data being stored?

Comment: If i will select any option value then it should be show as selected after refreshing the page, how it will possible>??

Comment: Well there are many different things you can do, but you're not being very clear on the desired outcome at the end of it all. For instance, you could store this value to a database for that specific user; you could store it as a cookie or a session variable; you could place a reference to it in the URL and retrieve it using `$_GET`, etc. After making the selection and before refreshing the page, what happens? Is a form submitted?

Comment: Define "refreshing" and **stop repeating yourself**

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `selected="selected"` to specify which option should be selected:

```
<option value="3" selected="selected">Test3/option>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is use the isset() function when you page loads